# Units of nutrient uptake rate in hydroponics?

Tags: nutrients

I'm studying the nutrient uptake by plants in hydroponics. I found that in many literatures, the uptake rate was expressed as xx (mg m<sup>-2</sup> hour<sup>-1</sup>). Does anyone know what does that per square meter mean? Is it per leaf area or per root area? You can find similar expression in this paper [link](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs11104-004-3093-z#/page-1), in Table 1., the uptake was expressed as xx mol m<sup>-2</sup> s<sup>-1</sup>

Comment: Interesting. For accuracy’s sake, could you render the formula more precisely, like by using `²` or `<sup>`?

Comment: Can you link to an example?

Comment: Probably leaf area, but I've never found hydroponics adequately riveting to really get into it.